# can't run an new created app by react-native

Tags: reactjs, emulation, native

I've weird problem with react native. My first app worked great on emulator and building was fine but now when I tried to run my second app on emulator i reciving an error:

- Could not connect to development server and possible fixes under it.

Why is this happening? I did all the same like last time when all worked.

Emulator is visible for adb:

```
C:\Users\Computer>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

react-native run-android:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 41.496 secs
Running ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Bartas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform- 
tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync 
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Bartas\AppData\Local\
Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
Starting the app on emulator-5554 
(ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Bartas\AppData\Local\An
droid\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n 
com.auth/com.auth.MainActivity)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, asked question too fast on stack.. Soory..

The problem was that my var had that value:

```
 'ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Bartas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform- tools/adb'
```

Just deleted 'ANDROID_HOME=' part and it works again.